# How to reduce procedure cacheusage from these statements without creating any additional indexes

Tags: sql-server

I plan to pass exam "Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012". 
I have one question that I have problem to understand. 
Question is:

> You are
>   developing a database application by using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.
>   An application that usesa database begins to run slowly. You discover
>   that a large amount of memory is consumed by single-use dynamic
>   queries. You need to reduce procedure cacheusage from these statements
>   without creating any additional indexes. What should you do?

Possible answers:
A.

> Add a HASH hint to the query.

B.

> Add a LOOP hint to the query.

C.

> Add a FORCESEEK hint to the query.

D.

> Add an INCLUDE clause to the index.

E.

> Add a FORCESCAN hint to the Attach query.

F.

> Add a columnstore index to cover the query.

G.

> Enable the optimize for ad hoc workloads option.

H.

> Cover the unique clustered index with a columnstore index.

I.

> Include a SET FORCEPLAN ON statement before you run the query.

J.

> Include a SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON statement before you run the
>   query.

K.

> Include a SET STATISTICS SHOWPLAN_XML ON statement before you run the
>   query.

L.

> Include a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ statement
>   before you run the  query.

M.

> Include a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT statement before
>   you run the query.

N.

> Include a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE statement
>   before you run the query.

Source: [You need to reduce procedure cacheusage from these statements without creating any additional indexes](http://www.aiotestking.com/microsoft/you-need-to-reduce-procedure-cacheusage-from-these-statements-without-creating-any-additional-indexes/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I am surprised though that they would ask you a question of this level in the beginner's level basic exam like `Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012`, these kind of questions (administrating sql server) should really be part of the SQL Server Administration exams I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would select **G**

```
Enable the optimize for ad hoc workloads option
```

Reason being as per MSDN recommendations:

> The optimize for ad hoc workloads option is used to improve the
>   efficiency of the plan cache for workloads that contain many single
>   use ad hoc batches. When this option is set to 1, the Database Engine
>   stores a small compiled plan stub in the plan cache when a batch is
>   compiled for the first time, instead of the full compiled plan. This
>   helps to relieve memory pressure by not allowing the plan cache to
>   become filled with compiled plans that are not reused.

MSDN link [`optimize for ad hoc workloads Server Configuration Option`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587.aspx)